# objective C Iphone open Google map application direction page url in webview memory warning

Tags: iphone, webview

HI, WHat am trying to do is load a google direction page directly in webview by passing the lat long values for source and destination (am getting these stored_long lat values that i have previously stored. and am not using google api) everything works fine but the prob is as soon as webview loads the direction page, it starts getting memory warning and on further browsing get crash need a solution to fix these ...am setting webview delegate to nil and also releasing webview also sometimes it crashes wen back btn is pressed ....do need urgent help...guys

NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/m?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f&view=map&z=13",Stored_lat3,Stored_long3,Stored_lat4,Stored_long4];

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:url]];

    aWebView.delegate = self;

    [aWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried profiling your application for Allocations using Instruments?

Memory warnings tend to imply your application is using too much memory. It could be that before you even open your web view you are using lots of memory. Opening the webview could be pushing your application over the edge so to speak.

Overriding didReceiveMemoryWarning in your view controllers to clean up memory is also a good tactic to prevent your application from crashing.

I hope this helps!

Comment: YA i tried using instrument ,you are right but dnt know what m doing wrong ,am releasing evry obj used , see am having a rootviewNAvigation controller, on that a view controlle is pushed whose view is being released as soon as i push webview..its eating say around 2.5 mb memory n keeps allcoting after termination to

Comment: hi i figured out the leak it causedby hostlookup_master, CFNetwork generalblock3854 how do i solve it ?